# How to call in RestController method from different Controller in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have RestController which look like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SimulationController {

@Autowired
    private SimulationRepository simulationRepository;

@PostMapping("/simulations")
    public Simulation createSimulation(@Valid @RequestBody Simulation simulation){
        simulationRepository.save(simulation);
       
        return simulation;

    }
}
```

I would like to know how can I pass simulation object to other Controller which can process data and save it to other repository. For example it could look like this:

```
@PostMapping("/simulations")
    public Simulation createSimulation(@Valid @RequestBody Simulation simulation){
        simulationRepository.save(simulation);
        SimulationProcess simulationProcess = new SimulationProcess(simulation);
        simulationProcess.simulate();
        return simulation;

    }
```

```
@Controller
public class SimulationProcess {
    private Simulation simulation;

    @Autowired
    private SecondRepository secondRepository;

    public SimulationProcess(Simulation simulation) {
        this.simulation = simulation;
    }

    public void simulate(){
    // process data from this.simulation
       secondRepository.save(new Second(...));
    }
}
```

But I know that this approach is not allowed. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You should create a RestTemplate object and call it as a simple Rest consumer.

Comment: Why don't you move your logic into services like FirstService (with first repo) and SecondService (with second repo) and you inject these services where you need them?

Comment: Another thing: why SimulationProcess (which looks like a very bad name to me :) ) has to be a controller? I cannot see any endpoint in it. You want that to be a @Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a **@Service** instead of a @Controller in your *SimulationProcess* class, you can inject it to your first controller and use it, but you can't map requests to a service (I think).

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SimulationController {

    @Autowired
    private SimulationRepository simulationRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SimulationProcess simulationProcess;

    @PostMapping("/simulations")
    public Simulation createSimulation(@Valid @RequestBody Simulation simulation){
        simulationRepository.save(simulation);

        simulationProcess.simulate(simulation);
       
        return simulation;

    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class SimulationProcess {

    @Autowired
    private SecondRepository secondRepository;

    public void simulate(Simulation simulation){
    // process data from this.simulation
       secondRepository.save(simulation);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps. And sorry for any mistakes, english is not my first language :D

Comment: Yeah, thanks it works now. But could you tell me if you know why I get only one save to secondRepository when I do it in for loop in method public void simulate?

Comment: When I do it by creating new object secondRepository.save(new Simulation(...) instead of secondRepository.save(simulation) it works. Why?

Comment: @Sikorkaa please show how your loop looks, seems a problem is here or try to debug it by yourself